# Creep Score Ratio Questions

Tags: league-of-legends

(1) What is a good CS ratio I must get on each meta-function (AD Carry, Jungler, Middle Lane, Support, Top Lane) at 10, 20, 30, 40 mins of game?

I want to improve my CS but I don't know about the average target values in each function.

I know that some events can change the score drastically, but I want the "ideal" or "average" values for reference only.

(2) Sometimes, if I'm not a Jungler, I kill minor jungle monsters near the lane. Does this affect my allied Jungler CS/experience? Must I avoid it?

(3) Is it true that a good Support needs to have near zero CS?

Comment: There are three distinct questions in this question. You need to separate them into different questions.

Comment: @JamesJiao Thanks James, I thought that as was little related question it wasnot worth to 3 different questions, but 3 points about the same question.

Comment: It's all related to Creep Score so... Its not really necessary.

Comment: Rule of thumb I use for Mid, top and ADC:  10 mins 75 cs. 20 mins 200 cs.  if you are at that level you are doing fine.  anything less, you need to work on your last hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start backwards:

***3***

Yes normally a good support will have close to 0 creep score. The support should let the ad carry get ALL the creeps. If the ad carry is not present the support should not push BUT it can last hit and get a couple minions if the turret would kill them anyway. But the general idea is to facilitate your carry to farm more, so even if the carry is back at a moment you shouldn't push the lane by farming.

***2***

Its ok to kill neutral creeps when the jungler is somewhere far away. Actually it's a well known tactic to kill the golems when they spawn at level 1, if the jungler starts at blue. Because by the time the jungler will come to the golems they will have respawned. The idea is to kill any minor camps you can if the jungler is busy somewhere else far from that camp. You don't want to steal your jungler's farm but you don't want to let those camps staying there unexploited for no reason either. 
So you have to have good awareness of the time it takes for those camps to respawn. If you think you don't you should probably leave them for your jungler.

***1***

There is nothing set in stone here. I'd say around 100 creeps at the 12-15 minute mark would be nice but it all depends on the game. What you should do as an ad carry is try to outfarm the other ad carry and you should have more farm than anyone in the game to be honest. Thats when you know that you're doing well. Every game is different. Some games include more ganks and more teamfights early. So you can't really set a number for CS score. Just last hit as much as you can without overpushing and try to beat everyone's else Creep Score.

Comment: Agreed on the support. Leave the CS to your carry, but it doesn't hurt to last-hit when the carry can't get it (for example, when he is back to base). There is no reason a support should have 0 CS

Comment: on point 2) Talk to your jungler!

Answer (score -1):

What's this question? You need all cs you can get except with support. Support must leave cs to carry. And about small camps near mid - if you jungler tries to more gank than farm jungles and he success at it, then you can take small camps. But if he has hard time with ganks, you should leave them to him, because he will fall behind with farm.